# How can I implement a global, implicit filter in Django admin?

Tags: django, filter, admin, permanent

A lot of my models have a foreign key to a "Company" model. Every logged in user can be part of one or more companies (User m2m Company, not null).

I would like the current admin user to have "Company goggles" on, i.e. a select list, on the admin index page or maybe the base header, where they can switch their "current" Company. Doing that should automatically apply a "company equals" filter - for models that have a foreign key to Company - in addition to any other filters.

What's the best way to achieve this?

NB: This is meant as a comfort function for the admin interface, actual protection of models is not necessary at this stage (client views do need that but I can just use a custom Manager and lookup via request.user there).

My current idea is:

1. Store current company in session.
2. Use middleware to look up current company from session, and append the company to all relevant links:

   a) change_list: (?/&)"company__eq=42"

   b) change_view "add?company=42" for models that have a foreign key to Company.

   This may require to reverse or pattern match the URLs to find out their model and check it for presence of the foreign key (or I might prepare that list beforehand to improve performance).
3. Include in each ModelAdmin form the foreign key field, but hide it via CSS, so that change_view add ("new") includes the preset foreign key value from the link without mentioning it.

Do you find this a viable approach?

If http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10761 was implemented I guess I could just specify a custom queryset which reads the current company from request.session and be done with it. Maybe better to fast-track (=make and submit patch) that ticket instead?

EDIT: or maybe just redefine the queryset() method on every ModelAdmin that needs it / has the foreign key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My vote is is for overriding `ModelAdmin.queryset`, since you conveniently have access to the request there. Override `save_model` for point 3.

```
 class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.session.get('company_goggles'):
             return qs.filter(company=request.session['company_goggles'])
        return qs
```

If you have many models, I'd subclass `ModelAdmin` as something like `GogglesAdmin` and define a field / default to pull the fieldname from and also the pre-save auto injecting of company.

```
class CompanyGogglesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CompanyGoggleAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.session.get('company_goggles'):
            return qs.filter(**{ getattr(self, 'company_field', 'company') : 
                          request.session['company_goggles'] })
```

By the way, I really like this "company goggles" terminology.

Comment: Thanks for this. Almost identical to lazerscience's answer, plus thank you for the idea with the base class and field name parameter. I think I'm all set now. Back to coding. :-)

Comment: NB: It should be "request.session.get('company_goggles', None)", not getattr() - request.session is dictionary-like.

Comment: Thanks Danny, I dunno what I was thinking. That stream of consciousness style coding!

Comment: The `queryset` method is now called `get_queryset`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last question: If you just want to display certain items of your queryset you can override the `ModelAdmin`'s `queryset()` method withoud problems. For example, if you'd set a company in the current session. You can furthermore overwrite the `save_model()` method to have the `company` `ForeignKey` always point to the user's company when saving the form:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        company = request.session.get('company', None)
        qs = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set()
        if not company is None:
            qs = qs.filter(company=company)
        return qs

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        company = request.session.get('company', None):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not change or not instance.company:
            instance.company = company
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

Comment: Ah, save_model(), of course! Thank you, I think all boxes are ticked on this now. :-)

Comment: And if you have many classes (and are too lazy to trivially find their base), how do you _globally_ register that - say - for all forms in a project?