# Django admin global implicit filter passed as URL part

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to implement a feature, similar to the one described in ["company-goggles" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344544"). Its answers suggest putting the value to filter against into user session, but I really dislike that and try to make it a part of URL instead.

To do this, I want to map any URL `admin/company/*/` to just  `admin/`, so I would be able to extract that value later in my `admin.py` models to apply the queryset filter against it.
Unfortunately, my naive attempts to play with the URL routers failed. The following doesn't seem to work:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/company/\w+/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/',             admin.site.urls),
]
```

If I remove the second patterns, admin panel got at least displayed, but it reverses all links to `admin/company/x/...`, and I really have no idea where it takes that `"x"` from. Trying using `include(admin.site.urls) with or without`namespace` parameter doesn't help either.

Is there a way to make link reverse work correctly?
Or may there be a conceptually better way to handle this issue?